# Почему код возвращает ошибку?

Tags: javascript

```js
let worker = {
  someMethod() {
    return 1;
  },

  slow(x) {
    alert("Called with " + x);
    return x * this.someMethod(); // (*)
  }
}

function decorator(func){

  let cashe = new Map();

  return function(x){

    if(cashe.has(x)){
      return cashe.get(x);
    }

    let result = func(x);

    cashe.set(x, result)

    return result

  }

};

worker.slow = decorator(worker.slow);


console.log( worker.slow(1) )
```

1. В **decorator** передаем метод **slow** объекта **worker**
2. **worker.slow** получает анонимную функцию из **decorator**
3. метод **slow** хранится в func т.к. анонимная функция помнит место создания (короче лексическое окружение)
4. **console.log( worker.slow() )** вызывает анонимную функцию
5. Она вызывает  **func(x)** т.е. метод **slow**
6. Выполняется **alert("Called with " + x);**
7. А затем **return x * this.someMethod();**
8. **result** получает **x * this.someMethod();**
9. **return** возвращает **x * this.someMethod();**
10. глобальное лексическое окружение получает **x * this.someMethod();**
11. получаем **undefined**
12. Верно скажите плиз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `func` внутри `decorator` оторвана от  `worker` и вызывается в глобальном контексте.

```js
let worker = {
  someMethod() {
    return 1;
  },
  slow(x) {
    alert("Called with " + x);
    return x * this.someMethod(); // (*)
  }
};

function decorator(func) {
  let cashe = new Map();

  return function(x) {
    if (cashe.has(x)) {
      return cashe.get(x);
    }

    let result = func(x);
    cashe.set(x, result);
    return result;
  };
};

worker.slow = decorator(worker.slow.bind(worker)); // !!! bind
console.log(worker.slow(1))
```

Comment: я вроде так и написал да ?

Comment: @user349791 В пунктах 9 и 10 написана ерунда.

Comment: короче возвращается result и он вызывается в глобальном контексте; а т.к. у нас strikt use то будет undefined ?

Comment: @user349791 Ошибка будет не из-из strict/не strict, а потому что у глобального объекта (в браузере - `window`) метода `someMethod` просто нет.

Comment: посмотрите правильно изменил алгоритм ?

Comment: @user349791 я не понимаю смысла этой фразы: "глобальное лексическое окружение получает ..."

Comment: глобальное лексическое окружение - это скрипт; локальное лексическое окружение это блок кода, условные операторы, операторы цикла, функции

Comment: 1) worker.slow возвращаем анонимную функцию 2) в консоле вызываем worker.slow(1) 3) где  func  в данном случае будет функцией а не методом верно ?

Comment: @user349791 3) - неверно. Это все равно метод, только метод глобального объекта (в браузере - `window`), который можно перед вызовом функции не писать.

Comment: можете наглядно показать что происходит ?